Should there be a see-also list of backlinks to "duplicate" questions?
The recent item,
Will there be forgiveness in the age to come?
was marked as a duplicate of
By the phrase "οὔτε ἐν τῷ μέλλοντι", was Jesus saying that there are sins that could be forgiven after death?.
People searching and finding the "age to come" question will correctly be referred to the second, where there are additional answers.
That is good.
But people that find the "after death" question will remain unaware of the other question and its answers, some of which might even be better than what is available in the target page.
That is bad.
Would it be appropriate and beneficial for the preferred page to include a see-also list of all its duplicate questions, some of which might contain answers that are better than what is in the preferred question's page?

Disclaimer: I'm using these two questions simply as an example of the situation, not implying that the two answers in the duplicate item (one of which is mine) are better.

It's a good idea - in cases of an exact duplicate we often Merge the questions to bring answers over from the duplicate to the original so they can enjoy a long, happy life. If this Q remains closed as a duplicate and is not edited to disambiguate, we will probably merge them in. That's not really an answer to your specific observation about needing more back-links, though.

There already is such a list! It's in the side panel:

It also includes other ways of linking than purely just duplicate questions, but most of the time that's adequate.

Either I'm blind and oblivious, or it really isn't obvious that that's what "Linked" means.
¶ I wonder how many people didn't know this, and how long it took the people that do know it to learn of it. ¶ I wonder how a typical user is supposed to know that that's what it means.
